# How do I put comment on each line in bash for printf?

Tags: linux, shell, printf, comments

I have the following code in my **Dockerfile**. Then I piped the output to my **setup.py**. I need to run this command in linux terminal. How can i put comment on each line?

```
  printf "%s\n" \
    # Facebook OAuth Client ID (default)
    "1234" \
    # Facebook OAuth Secret (default)
    "abcd" \
    # Google OAuth Client ID (default)
    "5678" \
    # Google OAuth Secret (default)
    "qwer" \
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using arrays in order to avoid long escaped by `\` lists of arguments is a good practice.
You can leave a comment for each element.

```sh
CREDENTIALS=(
    # Facebook OAuth Client ID (default)
    "1234"
    # Facebook OAuth Secret (default)
    "abcd"
    # Google OAuth Client ID (default)
    "5678"
    # Google OAuth Secret (default)
    "qwer"
)
printf "%s\n" "${CREDENTIALS[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "%s\n" \
    $(: 'Facebook OAuth Client ID (default)') \
    "1234" \
    $(: 'Facebook OAuth Secret (default)') \
    "abcd" \
    $(: 'Google OAuth Client ID (default)') \
    "5678" \
    $(: 'Google OAuth Secret (default)') \
    "qwer"
```

`$(command)` is command substitution, it gets replaced with the output of the command.

`:` is a command that does nothing and produces no output. The argument needs to be quoted because of the `(default)`, which would otherwise be executed as a command in a subshell.